# r: iterating through all elements of several columns to detect a phrase

Tags: r, text, iteration

i am trying to loop through several columns in a dataframe which contain text files.

i want to check every entry of columns 7 through 16 to see if any of the text files contain a certain phrase.

each time the phrase is detected, i want to increase the count of times it appeared by 1.

this seems pretty straightforward. i think i should iterate through the columns and by the rows, but i just can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this.

any suggestions? thank you in advance for any insight.

```
fc_count <- 0

for (col in profiles[7:16]){
  for (row in 1:nrow(profiles)){

    if(isTRUE(grepl("my name is jeff", row)) == TRUE){

      fc_count = fc_count + 1

    }

  }

}

fc_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns 7 to 16, apply `grepl`, with the `pattern` to get a `list` of logical vectors, `Reduce`, it to a single integer vector by adding (`+`) and then get the total value by `sum`

```
sum(Reduce(`+`, lapply(profiles[7:16], grepl, pattern = "my name is jeff")))
```

---

As `grepl` is vectorized for `vector`, if we convert the 'data.frame' to a `matrix` ( a `matrix` is a vector with dim attributes), it is more compact

```
sum(grepl("my name is jeff", as.matrix(profiles[7:16])))
```

---

Also, with `for` loops, we don't need the nested loops as `grepl` is vectorized

```
fc_count <- 0
for(prf in profiles[7:16]){
    fc_count <- fc_count + sum(grepl("my name is jeff", prf))
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much. do you know how i can do this using for loops?